# as a devops engineering what can perform with trigger in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

DevOps Engineering what can do with trigger? what is the use of trigger, i have little bit knowledge in building, but i need what can perform trigger in jenkins and it's need any plugin to trigger, if any plugin need what are they, give me small description about it.

Comment: There is no devops engineering.

Comment: devops can do trigger in devops, i might be not sure that in building stage

Comment: DevOps rules the world! Come on, you're a competent person, I guess, leave the devops shit out and focus on the Jenkins problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a web-hook which you can add in your git repository if you have admin access . An example of how to add a web-hook to your gitlab project you can refer :  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html

and for plugin on jenkins which is used to trigger builds you can see :
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gitlab+Hook+Plugin

and

https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin

Hope it helps.